# $M$ is smooth compact manifold and $C_0,C_1$ disjoint closed subsets of $M$ so there is exists smooth func $f:M \to [0,1]$ s.t $f(C_0)={0},f(C_1)={1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Before that exercise I've solved that:

> Show there is exists smooth function $\psi: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ s.t. $\psi (x) = 0$ for all $x \leq 0$ and $\psi(x)=1$ for all $x\geq 1 $.

And now they want us to solve that question with the exercise above.

- Exercise:

> $M$ is smooth compact manifold and $C_0,C_1$ disjoint closed subsets of $M$ so there is exists smooth func $f:M \to [0,1]$ s.t $f(C_0)={0},f(C_1)={1}$

I've seen similar questions but the solution were with unity of partition or tangent bundle, And I need to solve that only with atlas and mapping.

My attempt:
I want to find a smooth map (in local coordinates) $g: M \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $g(C_0) = (-\infty ,0]$ and $g(C_1) = [1,\infty)$ and $G(M \setminus (C_0 \cup C_1))=(0,1)$
and after I constructed that function I'll composite that function with $\psi$ and i've done.

But unfortunately I have no clue how to define a function like $g$ with the use of compactness of $C_0$ and $C_1$

I'll be glad if someone can give me any hint to do what I want or give me another idea to solve that question with the exercise i mentioned, Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you use mollifiers on $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @Alessandro I don't know what is mollifiers, But from the little I've read on that, I assume not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit cheating, since in the proof of existence of partition of unity we have similar constructions, but here we go.

First recall that by an open ball in $M$, we mean an open set $U$ together with a local coordinates chart
$$\varphi : U \to B_1,$$
where $B_1$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$.

Since $C_0$, $C_1$ are closed, they are compact since $M$ is. Then there are open balls
$$ U^0_1, \cdots, U_k^0$$
and
$$ U^1_1, \cdots, U^1_l$$
such that $U^0_i \cap U^1_j = \emptyset$ for all $i, j$, and the "half balls"
$$ V^0_1, \cdots, V_k^0$$
and
$$ V^1_1, \cdots, V^1_l$$
still covers $C_0$, $C_1$ respectively. Here the half balls are
$$V^\alpha_i = (\varphi^\alpha_i)^{-1} (B_{1/2}).$$

Now there is a smooth functions $\phi : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ so that $0\le \phi \le 1$, $\phi(y) = 1$ for all $|y|\le 1/2$ and $\phi(y) = 0$ for all $|y|>3/4$ (You may try to construct this $\phi$ using your $\psi$). Then for each $\alpha=0, 1$ and $i$, we can define a smooth function $\phi^\alpha_i$ on $M$ by

$$ \phi^\alpha _i (p) = \begin{cases} \phi (\varphi^\alpha_i (p)) & \text{ if } p \in U^\alpha_i, \\ 0 &\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}.$$

Let $g : M\to \mathbb R$ be the smooth function on $M$ defined by
$$ g = -\sum_{i=1}^k \phi^0_i + \sum _{j=1}^l \phi^1_j. $$

Then $g(p) \le -1$ for all $p\in C_0$ and $g(p)\ge1$ for all $p\in C_1$. This is what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why $\phi_{i}^{\alpha}$ is smooth (maybe it's related to the fact I don't understand what is the purpose of the $V_{i}^{\alpha}$)?

Comment: @oneneedsanswers $\varphi^\alpha_i$ are local chart, so they are smooth more or less by definition.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand why $\phi_{i}^{\alpha}$ is smooth, but I'm not sure why the $V_{i}^{\alpha}$ cover $C_{\alpha}$ and I want to make sure I understand, are the $U_{i}^{\alpha}$ defined by $(\varphi_{i}^{\alpha})^{-1}(B_{1})$?

Comment: Yes, local charts are by definition a homeomorphism. @oneneedsanswers You will need to construct the existence of such covers using the compactness of $C_0$ and $C_1$.

Comment: I understand how to construct the existence of $V_{i}^{\alpha}$, but I don't understand how to construct a cover of $U_{i}^{\alpha}$ where $V_{i}^{\alpha}$ (respectively to the $U_{i}^{\alpha}$) it's also a cover.

Comment: For all $x\in C_0$, there is a local chart $\varphi_x : U_x \to B_1$ so that $U_x$ is disjoint from $C_1$ and $\varphi_x(x) = 0$. Then $\{V_x := \varphi_x^{-1}(B_{1/2})\}_{x\in C_0}$ forms an open cover of $C_0$..... @oneneedsanswers

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that I understand how to construct the existence of that, but now why we need $U_{i} ^{0}$? There isn't a point $p \in C_0$ s.t. $p \in U_{i}^{0}$ and $p \notin V_{i}^{0}$ (and it may effect the smoothness of $\phi_{i}^{0}$ maybe?) , I'm really sorry if I don't get something easy, but I'm really not understand.